# How to launch an Android Emulator without Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator

A while ago there was an external AVD Manager app, outside of Android Studio. At some point it was removed. With AS 4.0 (or 3.x for that matter), is there any way to launch an existing AVD without Studio?

I'm not referring to 3rd party emulators such as Bluestacks, but to the emulator I use for development.

Answer (score 3):

You could start the emulator from the command line?
See official Android user guide: https://developer.android.com/studio/run/emulator-commandline

for example:

```
emulator -list-avds
AVD1
emulator -avd AVD1
```

You have not specified, which platform you are working on,
for macOS the emulator usually is located in Library/Android/sdk/emulator/