# Emulator starts with Exception code: 0xc0000005 on every launch

Tags: android, android-studio, crash, android-emulator

Everytime I launch/run my Android Studio emulator (Pixel 4 XL API 29) a new error pops up in Windows' Event Viewer. The error is the following:

```
Faulting application name: qemu-system-x86_64.exe, version: 0.0.0.0, time stamp: 0x60d50dd2
Faulting module name: MSVCP140.dll, version: 14.29.30037.0, time stamp: 0x609de407
Exception code: 0xc0000005
Fault offset: 0x0000000000013020
Faulting process id: 0x1e00
Faulting application start time: 0x01d7848725be898f
Faulting application path: C:\Users\<User>\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\emulator\qemu\windows-x86_64\qemu-system-x86_64.exe
Faulting module path: C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\MSVCP140.dll
Report Id: 58f04a8c-e4f8-4524-9646-cd0093854be6
Faulting package full name: 
Faulting package-relative application ID:
```

The thing is, the emulator runs just fine and it doesn't crash or anything. Just on every new launch of the emulator, this error appears in Event Viewer. I've checked Logcat logs (found nothing) and tried to start emulator from cli instead, same problem.

Since I found MSVCP140.dll to have come from Microsoft c++ 2015 redistributable x64, I've gone ahead and updated that redist as well with no change.
I've played around with emulator's memory settings (lowered and raised) to see if that makes a difference, but no change unfortunately.

`Exception code: 0xc0000005` is known for memory problems, so I've ran memory tools to verify nothing's wrong with memory (Windows RAM check, memtest86). No errors regarding memory.

What else can I check to understand what's causing this error?

*Edit
Adding Android studio about info:

```
Android Studio Arctic Fox | 2020.3.1
Build #AI-203.7717.56.2031.7583922, built on July 26, 2021
Runtime version: 11.0.10+0-b96-7249189 amd64
```

Answer (score 0):

I had and resolved the same issue.
The reason was I had an older version of Intel Hardware-accelerated execution Manager(HAXM) installed on Windows 10. While trying to run the emulator via command line I got this error: `Incompatible HAX module version 3, requires minimum version 4.` This occurred even when in the SDK tools of my android studio there was the correct version of HAXM.
So in the `Control panel-> remove software` **I uninstalled the older version and installed the newer version from the Intel site.**

P.S. To run the emulator follow this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62169205/how-to-launch-an-android-emulator-without-android-studio).